# BeautifulSoup get value from class

Tags: python, html, css, regex, beautifulsoup

I'm having troubles with BeautifulSoup.
Here's what I want to do:

> For each forms in each html page I read, I want to get the URL pointed by "action".

Here's my code:

```
def myfunction(path)
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    #Retrieve htmlFiles from a folder
    pages = find_files(path, '.html') #as a list
    for page in pages:
        stream = open(page, "rw")
        soup = BeautifulSoup(stream, "lxml")
        formsoup = soup.find('form', attrs={"method":u"post"})
        if formsoup is not None:
           action = soup.find('form', attrs={"method":u"post"}).findAll("action") 
           print "Action is => %s\n" % action
           print ("Source: %s\ncode: %s\n\n\n\n\n" % (page, formsoup))
    stream.close()
```

Here is the result I have:

```
Action is => []

    Source: mysource.html
    code: <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="http://actionIshouldget.com/" id="user-login" method="post"><div><div class="form-item form-type-textfield form-item-name">
[... hidhing about ~20 lines that are useless for me]
```

and here is the result I SHOULD have:

```
Action is => http://actionIshouldget.com/

    Source: mysource.html
    code: <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="http://actionIshouldget.com/" id="user-login" method="post"><div><div class="form-item form-type-textfield form-item-name">
[... hidhing about ~20 lines that are useless for me]
```

I didn't manage to use `for form in soup.find('form', attrs={"method":u"post"})` or regex...

Comment: What's your HTML file looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`findAll()` will try to find sub-elements in the structure that you have, and in your case it searches for `<action>` elements.

Have you tried this?

```
formsoup = soup.find('form', attrs={"method":u"post"})
formsoup['action']
```

Comment: Well yeah that's the first thing I tested...
I probably didnt drink enough coffee this morning, this works great...
Thanks and sorry for useless topic then